# Server calls for every View Redirect(Change) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I have an usual AngularJS Controller:

```
controllers.UController = function ($scope, uFactory) {
$scope.data1 = uFactory.getDataUsingAjax1(); 
$scope.data2 = uFactory.getDataUsingAjax2(); 
$scope.data3 = uFactory.getDataUsingAjax3(); 
...
}
```

The mentioned fields (data1 - data3) gets populated using Ajax call.
I also have several Views.

When I run my app the first time, I can see all the 3 Ajax calls in order to populate data1-data3.
But every time I redirect to another View, I can see that this population starts again and again.
In my understanding it's not really a SPA architecture or it's a bad SPA.
Is this how it should work or I am missing something?

Comment: Can you share the Factory code, Look like bad SPA

Comment: can u share ur factory code and also what is the controller in ur new view(navigated view)?

Comment: some things to look out for _1)_ are you refreshing/redirecting the page (full page reload) _2)_ you're using ui-router - your use of `ui-view` as well as your route definition could be causing this (parent-child OR abstract views). We need more info here

Comment: guys, I published the details below

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{
controller: 'UController',
templateUrl: '/Partial/View1.html'
})
.when('/View2',
{
controller: 'UController',
templateUrl: '/Partial/View2.html'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/View3' });
}]);



myApp.factory('uFactory', function () {
var factory = {};
data1 = [];
data2 = [];

factory.getAjaxData1 = function () {
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
contentType: "application/json",
async: false,
success: function (result) {
data1= result;
}
});

return data1;
}

factory.getAjaxData2 = function () {
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
contentType: "application/json",
async: false,
success: function (result) {
data2= result;
}
});

return data2;
}
}



var controllers = {};

controllers.uController = function ($scope, $location, uFactory) {

$scope.data1 = uFactory.getAjaxData1();

$scope.data2 = uFactory.getAjaxData2();

}
```

Redirection is done by href link:
    a href="#/View1"Do it/a